# JS insert into array at specific index

Tags: javascript, arrays

I would like to insert a string into an array at a specific index. How can I do that?

I tried to use push()

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Well, thats pretty easy. Assuming you have an array with 5 objects inside and you want to insert a string at index 2 you can simply use javascripts array splice method:

```
var array = ['foo', 'bar', 1, 2, 3],
        insertAtIndex = 2,
        stringToBeInserted = 'someString';

// insert string 'someString' into the array at index 2
array.splice( insertAtIndex, 0, stringToBeInserted );
```

Your result will be now:

```
['foo', 'bar', 'someString', 1, 2, 3]
```

FYI: The push() method you used just adds new items to the end of an array (and returns the new length)

Comment: Note that the returned value from `splice` function is an empty array. `splice` directly applies the changes to the array.