# How to insert specific index in array using lodash?

Tags: javascript, lodash

I already see the lodash documentation but I don't know what function do I need to use to solve my problem. I have array

```
const arr = [
  {name: 'john'},
  {name: 'jane'},
  {name: 'saske'},
  {name: 'jake'},
  {name: 'baki'} 
]
```

I want to add `{name: 'ace'}` before saske. I know about splice in javascript, but I want to know if this is possible in lodash.

Comment: Please read this thread, you'll have idea. https://github.com/lodash/lodash/issues/89

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to insert an item into an array at a specific index (JavaScript)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/586182/how-to-insert-an-item-into-an-array-at-a-specific-index-javascript) and [JS insert into array at specific index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32024319)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**You can try something like this:**

---

```js
const arr = [{
    name: 'john'
  },
  {
    name: 'jane'
  },
  {
    name: 'saske'
  },
  {
    name: 'jake'
  },
  {
    name: 'baki'
  }
]

const insert = (arr, index, newItem) => [
  ...arr.slice(0, index),

  newItem,

  ...arr.slice(index)
];

const newArr = insert(arr, 2, {
  name: 'ace'
});

console.log(newArr);
```

Answer (score 22):

Currently [lodash](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11) not have that. You can use this alternate

```
arr.splice(index, 0, item);
```

```js
const arr = [
  {name: 'john'},
  {name: 'jane'},
  {name: 'saske'},
  {name: 'jake'},
  {name: 'baki'} 
]

arr.splice(2, 0, {name: 'ace'})

console.log(arr)
```

Comment: Perfect one-liner

Answer (score 1):

There is no support of such functionality in lodash :  [see issue](https://github.com/lodash/lodash/issues/89).

If you still want it to look like done with lodash, then you can do it like this way.

```
fields = [{name: 'john'},
          {name: 'jane'},
          {name: 'saske'},
          {name: 'jake'},
          {name: 'baki'}
         ];

_.insert = function (arr, index, item) {
  arr.splice(index, 0, item);
};

_.insert(fields,2,{'name':'ace'});

console.log(fields);
```

Comment: Insert is on way to be supported in lodash: https://github.com/lodash/lodash/pull/4567